# How to get count of all columns of a table, which are not null using PL/SQL?

Tags: css, plsql, count, multiple-columns

Is there any PL/SQL function, which allows to pass a table name and returns the count of all columns, which don't include null values?

I have a huge number of columns and don't want to query each and every column. I'm new to PL/SQL and highly appreciate your help.

Comment: I have tried this query but its not giving the correct result..total count of the table is wrong using the below query..             select t.table_name, T.NUM_ROWS, c.column_name, c.num_nulls, T.NUM_ROWS - c.num_nulls num_not_nulls, c.data_type, c.last_analyzed from all_tab_cols c                              join sys.all_all_tables t on C.TABLE_NAME = t.table_name where c.table_name like 'EXT%' and c.nullable ='Y'                                                   group by t.table_name, T.NUM_ROWS, c.column_name, c.num_nulls, c.data_type, c.last_analyzed order by t.table_name, c.column_name;

Comment: Instead of posting the query within the comment you should edit your question and add it there formatted, so it's more readable.

Comment: I got the result using above query..Thanks for responding..There was a mismatch of the total no of rows,am able resolve it by gathering statistics on the table

Comment: If I understand you right, you could already solve your problem. In that case you may want to [post an answer for your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Though note that you need at least 15 reputation for this. This helps others if they face the same problem.

Comment: I couldnt post the answerdue to the minimal reputations..The above query I posted earlier resolved my issue..

Comment: Ok, so as I said before, you should post the query as answer as soon as you have enough reputation. I could also do that for you, but then I would get the points for it if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of a comment to the question one approach to solve this is the following query:

```
SELECT t.table_name,
       t.num_rows,
       c.column_name,
       c.num_nulls,
       t.num_rows - c.num_nulls num_not_nulls,
       c.data_type,
       c.last_analyzed
FROM all_tab_cols c
JOIN sys.all_all_tables t ON c.table_name = t.table_name
WHERE c.table_name LIKE 'EXT%'
  AND c.nullable = 'Y'
GROUP BY t.table_name,
         t.num_rows,
         c.column_name,
         c.num_nulls,
         c.data_type,
         c.last_analyzed
ORDER BY t.table_name,
         c.column_name
```